# java command line switch to disable expiredCert checking?

Tags: java, ssl

I have a java app that is being tripped up by an expired cert.

There is a command line switch to bypass checking the revocation
`-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=false` but I can't find one to bypass expiration (i tried `-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkExpiration=false` but that would have been too simple).

Anyone have a way to bypass checking a certs expiration (or a link to a comprehensive list of -D switches that I could explore...)?